# Not able to collapse the first row in datagrid in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I am using a Silverlight datagrid control which should appear 'collapsed' by default. I found the sample code in msdn. But it shows error message that "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index. " . Below is my code.

```
private void CollapseGrid()
        {
            PagedCollectionView pcv = MyGrid.ItemsSource as PagedCollectionView;
            try
            {
                foreach (CollectionViewGroup group in pcv.Groups)
                {
                    MyGrid.CollapseRowGroup(group, true);
                    MyGrid.ScrollIntoView(group, null);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Could not collapse group.
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue fixed. I am populating the datagrid through an asynchronous call. So there is no way to check whether this call is completed or not. My collapse method will be called before completion of populating data in datagrid. So found a solution from one of the sites. Below is the solution.

```
void myDataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    myDataGrid.LoadingRow -= new EventHandler<DataGridRowEventArgs>(myDataGrid_LoadingRow);
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate
    {
        PagedCollectionView pcv = (PagedCollectionView)myDataGrid.ItemsSource;
        foreach (CollectionViewGroup groupname in pcv.Groups)
        {
          myDataGrid.CollapseRowGroup(groupname, true);
        }
     });
}
```

In the datagrid part of xaml, we need to add this event.

```
<sdk:DataGrid LoadingRow = "myDataGrid_LoadingRow"  ItemsSource="{Binding MyBindingSource}">
```